# text based game inventory issues

Tags: python

```
def game_instructions():
   #print a main menu and the commands
   print("Lion Text Adventure Game")
   print("Collect 6 items to win the game, or be Attacked by the Lion.")
   print('Move Commands: North , South , East , or West.')
   print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")
game_instructions()

#Shows rooms available to move and items in each room
rooms = {
        'Auditorium': {'North': 'Info Exhibit', 'East': 'Library', 'South': 'Utility Room', 'West': 'Storage'},
        'Info Exhibit': {'South': 'Auditorium', 'East': 'Observation Area', 'item': 'Tranquilizer Gun'},
        'Observation Area': {'West': 'Info Exhibit', 'item': 'Lion'},
        'Storage': {'East': 'Auditorium', 'item': 'Tranquilizer Darts'},
        'Utility Room': {'North': 'Auditorium', 'East': 'Cafeteria', 'item': 'Night Vision Goggles'},
        'Library': {'West': 'Auditorium', 'North': 'Office', 'item': 'Facts Book'},
        'Office': {'South': 'Library', 'item': 'Keys'},
        'Cafeteria': {'West': 'Utility Room', 'item': 'Steak'},
    }


current_room = 'Auditorium' # starts player in the Great Hall
inventory = [] # Adds an inventory
def get_new_room(current_room, direction):
    new_room = current_room # declares new room as current room.
    for i in rooms: # starts loop
        if i == current_room: # if statement
            if direction in rooms[i]: # if statement
                new_room = rooms[i][direction] # Assigns new room.
    return new_room #returns new room

def get_item(current_room):
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]: #if statement
        return rooms[current_room]['item'] #return statement
    else:
        return 'This room has no item!' #return statement

while (current_room): # gameplay loop
    print('You are in', current_room) # tells player what room they are in.
    print('Inventory:', inventory) # shows player their inventory
    item = get_item(current_room)  # defines item as get item
    print('You found the:', item) # tells the player what item they have found
    if item == 'Lion': #if statement
        print('The Lion found you before you collected all the necessary items to survive! The game has ended!')  # notifies player game has ended.
        break  # ends game
    direction = input('Enter direction you would like to move. >>') # gets direction from player.
    direction = direction.capitalize() # Capitalizes the players input to match what is in the dictionary.

    if (direction == 'North' or direction == 'South' or direction == 'East' or direction == 'West'): # if statement
        new_room = get_new_room(current_room, direction) # Calling function
        if new_room == current_room: # if statement
            print('That is a wall not an exit. Try Again!') # Print statement
        else:
            current_room = new_room # declares current room as new room
    elif direction == str('get '+item): #input statement to add item
        if 'item' in inventory: # if statement
            print('You have already collected this item. Move to another room!') #print statement
        else:
            inventory.append(item) # adds item to inventory
    else:
        print('Not a valid direction!') # Print statement
    if len(inventory)==6: # if statement
        print('Congratulations!! You have collected all the necessary items and have safely put the lion back in his exhibit!') # print statement
```

I am trying to make a text based game. Everything is working besides the code is not adding my item to the inventory. When I input get and item name it is just saying invalid direction and not adding it. Iv looked it over and I can not see where I am going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated ! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you capitalized the input here,

```
direction = input('Enter direction you would like to move. >>') # gets direction from player.
direction = direction.capitalize() # Capitalizes the players input to match what is in the dictionary.
```

The elif statement would have never been true, if you add capitalize to that condition then it works.

```
elif direction == str('get '+item).capitalize():
```

Always make sure you work with the same kind of string.

Comment: I changed it and it is still showing my inventory as empty.

Comment: I tried with this, first enter north, and then 'get item_name'

output:

Lion Text Adventure Game
Collect 6 items to win the game, or be Attacked by the Lion.
Move Commands: North , South , East , or West.
Add to Inventory: get 'item name'
You are in Auditorium
Inventory: []
You found the: This room has no item!
Enter direction you would like to move. >>north
You are in Info Exhibit
Inventory: []
You found the: Tranquilizer Gun
Enter direction you would like to move. >>get tranquilizer gun
You are in Info Exhibit
Inventory: ['Tranquilizer Gun']
You found the: Tranquilizer Gun